# CASE WHEN With multiple

Tags: sql-server, case-when

I have a statement that is working:

```
CASE [Level 1]
WHEN '2017' THEN ''
WHEN '2016' THEN '' 
WHEN '2015' THEN ''
WHEN '2014' THEN ''
ELSE [Level 1]
END
```

I was trying to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
CASE WHEN [LEVEL 1]
LIKE 'CALENDAR MONTH%' THEN 'CALENDAR MONTH'
LIKE 'CALENDAR WEEK%' THEN 'CALENDAR WEEK'
LIKE 'CALENDAR QUARTER%' THEN 'CALENDAR QUARTER'
ELSE '[LEVEL 1]
END
```

Suggestions on how to make this second statement work?

Comment: Seem to have an extra single quote in your ELSE statement. Start by removing that. I assume it's a typo in the question though, since otherwise you'd get a syntax error when you tried to run this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
  CASE WHEN [LEVEL 1] LIKE 'CALENDAR MONTH%' THEN 'CALENDAR MONTH'
       WHEN [LEVEL 1] LIKE 'CALENDAR WEEK%' THEN 'CALENDAR WEEK'
       WHEN [LEVEL 1] LIKE 'CALENDAR QUARTER%' THEN 'CALENDAR QUARTER'
       ELSE [LEVEL 1]
  END
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!